# Why my models have a pretty high accuracy with a small training dataset?

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees, svm, accuracy, overfitting

I was wondering why my models (decision tree, svm, random forest) behave like that, with "high" accuracy on a small training dataset. Is it a sign of overfitting?
The graph represents the accuracy measured on training datasets with different sizes, from 0.01 to 0.9 of the total dataset.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1cTj.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be overfit or just good models (maybe the prblem is easy). In order to determine you should compare the results on the train set to the results on a validation/ test set.

Comment: My accuracy on the training dataset is higher +0.07/0.1 than my accuracy on the test datest I think.

Comment: If this is a big gap for you - this is a problematic overfit. If this is a small gap - you have good test results (they are similar to the trai results) which is great.

Comment: Yeah thats what I dont know, how can i say that its a small/big gap? Can you please elaborate, maybe with an example? Thanks

Comment: That depends mainly on your problem and goals.